# ¿Como enviar datos de mi vista a controlador por ajax en laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo mi view en la cual muestro un pequeño formulario para ingresar correo y Movil.
Además, también paso a esta misma view resultados de consultas a mi BD y las imprimo en pantalla.

Lo que quiero lograr es que al hacer clic en el botón de enviar formulario el correo, el Num.Telefono más algunos id que paso a esta vista, se envien a un controlador y este guardara estos datos en la BD.

He logrado capturar El correo, Movil y los id que quiero, por medio de JavaScript, ya que al hacer clic en botón de submit hago un console.log y me muestra el objeto con los datos en la consola.

Investigando descubrí que con ajax se puede enviar mis variables a mi controlador y sin recargar mi página!
Realice la estructura del envio con ajax pero al dar clic en enviar mis datos se muestran en la url como si se enviaran por GET, y tengo puesto el **type: 'POST'** y mi ruta al controlador que recibira estos datos igual esta en **POST**. Y no, mi controlador no recibe nada de datos ya que en mi tabla en la BD no hay datos.

Soy nuevo con ajax y ya intenté varias cosas y no funciona.

Mi formulario en mi view

```
                <form id="formulario">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="IdA" value="{{ $kardex->IdA }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="IdEstatus" value="S">
                <input type="hidden" name="fecha" value="{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}">
                <label for="email">Correo electronico</label><br>
                <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo"><br>
                <label for="phone">Confirma tu numero</label><br>
                <input type="tel" id="cel" name="cel"><br>
                <button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="btnout">Enviar</button>
            </form>
```

Mi codigo JavaScript con ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnEnviar').submit(function(event) {
    // Obtener la fecha actual
    event.preventDefault();
    var fechaSolicitud = new Date();
    var Fecha_Solicitud = fechaSolicitud.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");

    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $('#fecha_solicitud').val(Fecha_Solicitud);

    // crear objeto con los datos
    var formData = {
        _token: csrfToken, 
        IdA: kardex.IdA,
        IdEstatus: 'S',
        FechaSolicitud: formattedFechaSolicitud,
        FechaEnvio: formattedFechaSolicitud,
        CorreoElectronico: $('#correo').val(),
        Movil: $('#cel').val(),
    };
    console.log(formData);
    // Realizar la solicitud AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/solicitudes',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Mi ruta en web.php

```
Route::post('/solicitudes', [solicitudecController::class,'guardars'])->name('solicitudes');
```

Mi controlador

```
    public function guardars(Request $request){


    $formData = [
        $IdA = $request->all('IdA'),
        $IdEstatus = $request->all('IdEstatus'),
        $FechaSolicitud = $request-> all('FechaSolicitud'),
        $FechaEnvio = $request-> all('FechaEnvio'),
        $CorreoElectronico= $request-> all('CorreoElectronico'),
        $Movil= $request->all('Movil'),

    ];
    // dd($data);

    DB::table('Solicitudes')->insert([
        'IdA' => $IdA,
        'IdEstatus' => $IdEstatus,
        'FechaSolicitud' => $FechaSolicitud,
        'FechaEnvio' =>$FechaEnvio,
        'CorreoElectronico' => $CorreoElectronico,
        'Movil' => $Movil,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Puedes enviar todo a través de data (primero define tus variables): `data: "correo="+correo+ "&movil=" + movil + "&fecha=" + fecha`
Si lo quieres enviar como un objeto como lo estás haciendo, debes enviarlo como json.